# My WordPress site can't sent email like woocommerce check out

Tags: wordpress, email, host

I have an WordPress site
Last night I saw this problem after checkout customer can't get the mail and after table reservation customer can't get the mail

I think it's hosting configuration error
So what can I do it on host

Answer (score 0):

Check your mail logs or configure the website to use a plugin that allows you to directly send mail through smtp. You may get bounce backs (if spam blocked or other errors). It's impossible to troubleshoot with little information.

Answer (score 0):

This is the regular error on WordPress
use `wp smptp` plugin which will provide email service providers then you can send emails.